# Case fans - 140mm

Tags: cooling

Due to some poor airflow in my case i'm looking to replace my default case fans and add 2 more.

As a case i have Sharkoon AI7000 and my mb is Aorus X470.

I've been looking around in my local market and i stumbled upon 3 fans.

One is the **Arctic Bionix F140** which has PWM PST (sharing)- https://www.arctic.ac/eu_en/bionix-f140.html

The other one that was recommended to me was **Noctua NF-p14s redux** https://noctua.at/en/nf-p14s-redux-1200-pwm (to use as 2* intake fans).

And for exhaust i was recommended the 1500 pwm version of the Noctua https://noctua.at/en/nf-p14s-redux-1500-pwm

Since on paper the Arctic fan seems to be better i thought i'd ask here too.

Any tips ? Both have the same price in my country (1$ difference) and i need 5 (2 front, 1 back, 2 top).

The airflow in my case is a bit bad (got RTX 2080 with Ryzen 7 2700X and my GPU seems to make my CPU hotter), more on the issue here -> https://superuser.com/questions/1395950/fixing-airflow-in-pc-case/1395957?noredirect=1#comment2105355_1395957

If you've got any other recommendations i could look them up to see if they are available in my country, but i'd like to stay in the same price range if possible (since i need 5).

Comment: Be warned - the specs provided are not worth the paper they are written on. And there isn't that much of a difference in airflow between fans (assuming equal speed & size), though there can be significant differences in noise. Most likely you need to improve the smooth flow of air over the hotter components, rather than simply trying to push more air in/out.

Comment: Your Superuser question is the one you want to pursue - you problem will not be fixed by more fans but by better management of air flow.

Comment: For anyone else looking for a recommendation for a quiet, effective fan, the Noctua P12/P14's are excellent.

Comment: @CJM well there's nothing much i can do with my current case to fix the airflow. Wire management is done and the HW is new, which is why i'm looking to improve my case fans. Anyway, so you're saying the P14's should be better than the Arctic Bionix F140 ?

Comment: No, I'm saying the Noctua's are great. I know nothing about the F40. However, I'd be surprised if you cannot improve the cooling without fans. Does the GFX exhaust have a way to get out without passing over the CPU? If so, try blocking off the two using a piece of card, redirecting the GPU exhaust out of the case but bypassing the CPU HSF.

Comment: Also, when your CPU is registering 55C (warm but not excessively hot), does the heatsink feel warm to the touch? it could be that the heat is not being transferred through the HSF properly; if so check you the mounting and thermal paste.

Comment: @CJM unfortunately i dont think i can block it, here's a pic (the sagging has been fixed ) https://i.stack.imgur.com/0XJNJ.jpg . I haven';t checked the heatsink, but the case (the glass) itself feels rather warm. My cpu doesnt overheat from this issue, but the RPM on the cooler does go high because of it.

Comment: I can see you have a sideways facing CPU HSF which is poor - rather than push hot air towards the upper/rear exhaust fans, it is pushing it back into the case. Combined with your GFX generating case heat, you are going to have a problem. The upper fans will really have to fight to get hold of the hot air from below, and you will probably find that there will be a nice cool airflow around the top of the case without passing over the hot components.

Comment: De-pimp your HSF and get one pushing backwards or upwards and you will see a big difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Been a long while since i posted this, but i thought i'd throw out an answer in case this comes up in searches.

It is indeed an airflow problem, but i fixed it without changing the CPU cooler. 
I've bought 5x ARCTIC AC BioniX F140 and placed them like this -> 2 front in, 2 top out, 1 back out.

This keeps everything cooler since the hot air generated from my RTX can get out a bit faster and the power of those fans is quite nice (but damn they are loud sometimes). They have PWM sharing so i set them up like 2+2+1 in PWM slots so they dont go crazy with no reason (trust me, 5 of those running at 100% will make you think you're in an airport).

For the price (about 80$ for all 5) they are fine, but they are extremely loud at full speed.

Answer (score 0):

Try this [link](https://mywaywealth.com):  Hope it helps,
https://mdcomputers.in/nzxt-aer-rgb-2-140mm-hf-28140-b1.html?gclid=CjwKCAjw8NfrBRA7EiwAfiVJpTkNCAPsmRtGpgPLexaFjdqd3kj4arbMjIBcL0nS0q2kZWhUsaMmyxoCI9IQAvD_BwE

Comment: That is not worth the money in any way....Its overpriced because of the RGB (which i'm not interested in). Also as i've answered my post below i have fixed the issue long ago.